# Find how many solutions the congruence $x^2\equiv -1 \mod 61$ has

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I tried it has two solutions $\pm 30!~mod~61$ but I need explicitely what are those? I have seen similar problems in this site but I didn't get the solution completely.

Comment: If you want to know how *many* solutions there are, as the title requests, the number is simply $2$, since $61$ is a prime congruent to $1$ mod $4$. If you need to know explicitly what the solutions are, as the body of the question indicates, you have at most $30$ numbers to try, namely $x^2=1^2$, $2^2$, up to $30^2$, since the other solution will be $61-x$.

Comment: I'd do it like $x^2+1\equiv x^2-121\equiv(x-11)(x+11)\equiv 0\pmod{61}$ so $x\equiv \pm 11\pmod{61}$ but this might not work in general.

Comment: Just a small remark: There are at most two solutions, because $61$ is prime. There might also be no solutions at all. As $61 = 4\cdot 15 + 1$, we know that there are exactly two, but for primes that are $-1$ mod $4$ there will be none.

Comment: @Dirk, thanks for adding your comment. I had forgotten to include the mod $4$ condition in my own (but managed to edit it in during the five-minute grace period).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $61=5^2+6^2$. So $5^2\equiv-6^2\pmod{61}$. Now $6\cdot51\equiv1\pmod{61}$, so 
$$(5\cdot51)^2\equiv-1\pmod{61}.$$
Now $5\cdot51=255\equiv11\pmod{61}$. So the two solutions to the congruence are $\pm11\pmod{61}$.

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: @kingW3 Thanks for the correction. I have changed the answer.

Comment: how did you thought $61=5^2+6^2$

Comment: how suddenly 51 comes

Comment: @GopiS The primes $p$ for which $x^2\equiv -1\pmod p$ has solutions are exactly the same primes that are the sum of two squares. Once you know that $61$ is the sum of two squares, finding those two squares isn't difficult. $51$ is probably most easily found using the extended Euclidean algorithm on $6$ and $61$.

Comment: I knew $61$ is the sum of two squares, and I found $5^2+6^2$ by trial. As to $51$, it is easy to note that $6\cdot10\equiv-1\pmod{61}$, so $6\cdot-10\equiv1\pmod{61}$.

Comment: Thank you ...Now I got it@awllower and @arthur